# NSUrl is not recognized by Foundation namespace

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsurl

I am building in Visual Studio an iOS Binding Library. Objective Sharpie generated a code in ApiDefinition.cs. I am using directive namespace "Foundation" but clicking F12 at "Foundation" is not redirecting me to namespace definition. The "NSURL" type is not recognized. Other classes like "NSString" etc. are recognized well. There is an error:

```
CS0246  C# The type or namespace name 'NSURL' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What should I do to make 'NSUrl' recognized?

Comment: There are some differences between iOS and Xamarin.iOS in name of Object.For example ,`NSURL` in OC and `NSUrl` in C#.You need to manually modify it.

Comment: [Binding iOS libraries in Xamarin](https://www.jimbobbennett.io/binding-ios-libraries-in-xamarin/) is a good overview of the types of manual changes that will need to be done to the bindings generated by Objective Sharpie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will prompt a large number of errors . Such as

[image]
[image]
You have to do something. For example, use the `ulong/long` instead of `nuint` ,and annotate the  code such as `[Verify(MethodToProperty)]` .In addition,there are some differences between iOS and Xamarin.iOS in name of Object.For example ,NSURL in OC and NSUrl in C#.You need to manually modify it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out NSURL in Objective-C is NSUrl in C#.